# How does Privoxy filter DNS requests if it only supports HTTP/S traffic?

Tags: networking, dns, proxy, privoxy

Privoxy is a web proxy which deals exclusively with HTTP/S web traffic:

> Please note that Privoxy can only proxy HTTP and HTTPS traffic

source: https://www.privoxy.org/3.0.26/user-manual/startup.html

However, one of the main features of Privoxy is to filter domain names to remove ads etc. For example:

```
{ +block }
www.ad.example1.com
ad.example2.com
ads.galore.example.com
etc.example.com
```

To block unwanted domains, it must be also intercepting DNS requests. However DNS requests are not HTTPS - they're normally UDP.

Question:

1. Does privoxy intercept DNS requests? Or does it work differently than I thought?
2. If it is intercepting these DNS requests, why does it not log this anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Privoxy doesn't need to intercept DNS commands, because it intercepts
the URL being requested well before the stage where the DNS request is
required or issued.

It can then block the URL, based solely on the domain-name that it contains,
if that domain-name appears in the blacklist.

Comment: I'm sure you are correct, but I'm not quite sure how that works for applications that invoke `getaddrinfo(3)` or its equivalents in other languages before issuing a call to `Sockets.Connect(newPort, remoteAddrandPort, addrlen)`? can you help me fill that gap in understanding?

Comment: @FrankThomas - bear in mind that the browser (or client using Privoxy) is no longer responsible for fetching the data from the URL and hence does not need to resolve the IP address, it is handing off that responsibility to Privoxy which then acts on behalf of the web browser. Privoxy is the one doing the resolving and the fetching, not the web browser - but only if the various Privoxy filters allow it. Hence why this answer is correct. HTH

Comment: @FrankThomas - Additionally, if you are concerned that the Privoxy filters do not block unknown undesirable destinations, you could point the host that is running Privoxy to a PiHole or AdGuard server, or similar [DNS blocking service](https://adguard-dns.io/kb/general/dns-providers/) and ensure that you can also preemptively block via a DNS lookup. If you want to use an HTTP/S proxy like Squid or nginx etc, that would pass requests to Privoxy, they can be configured to resolve via specific DNS servers, i.e. PiHole or AdGuard, before passing the request onto Privoxy. HTH